# how to make drop down non editable in vb (ms access)?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

how to make drop down non editable in vb (ms access)? i couldnt find the property "dropdown style" as browsed. "Locked" & "Items in List" properties doesn't work. The "Locked" property made it non-editable, but not able to select other options in the dropdown.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: All WinForms controls have a Enabled property which you can set to false. Btw..are you talking about a [ComboBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox(v=vs.110).aspx) ?

Comment: @AlexB. I think they want the `DropDownList` style where users cannot type into the ComboBox but can still use it

Answer (score 2):

Use the LimitToList property - this will prevent anything other than list items being selected. If you type a new entry you'll get a message telling you that it's not in the list.